# Grails unit test case showing Completed 0 spock test, 0 failed

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.2

I am new to Grails. I am using version 2.2.2 
My test cases are not running even it says test cases passed. 
I get the following message after running the test case.

> Resolving [test] dependencies...
>   Resolving [runtime] dependencies...
>   | Compiling 1 source files.
>   | Error log4j:ERROR Property missing when configuring log4j: grails
>   | Error log4j:ERROR Property missing when configuring log4j: grails
>   | Error log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: null
>   | **Completed 0 spock test, 0 failed in 1409ms**
>   | Tests PASSED - view reports in D:\workspace_idea\optapp\target\test-reports

```
@TestFor(KpiLog)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
@Mock(KpiLog)
class KpiLogSpec extends Specification {

    void "savelog"() {
        prinln "*********"
        when:
        def kpiLog = new KpiLog(scenarioId: 1, kpiId: 2, deltaKpi: 5)
        kpiLog.save(flush: true)

        then:
        KpiLog.list()!= null
    }

    void testSaveFacebookUser(){
        //given
        def kpiLog = new KpiLog(scenarioId: 1, kpiId: 2, deltaKpi: 5)
        //adminRole.addToPermissions("*:*")
        kpiLog.save()
    }
}
```

Can some one please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong?

I am running the test case as `grails test-app -unit KpiLogSpec`

Here is the log4j section from the Config.groovy file

```
    log4j = {
// Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
// appender:
//
//appenders {
//    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
//}
debug 'grails.app'
error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

appenders {
    console name:'S', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d %-5p %c - %m%n')
    //rollingFile name: 'R', file:'/usr/local/jd/logs/optimizer.log',maxFileSize: '5000000KB'
    rollingFile name: 'R', file:grails.config.logPath, maxFileSize: '5000000KB'
    environments {
        production {
            appender new AWSSNSAppender(
                name:'SNS' ,
                topicName:config.optimizer.snsAppender.topicName,
                topicSubject:config.optimizer.snsAppender.topicSubject,
                awsAccessKey:config.optimizer.aws.accessKey,
                awsSecretKey:config.optimizer.aws.secretKey,
                threshold:Level.toLevel(optimizer.snsAppender.threshold, Level.ERROR)
            )
        }
    }
}
info R: ['NotifierService', 'aggDataStackLog','constraintGroupLog','pageFilterLog','alertDebugLog','dacCacLog','tpFlagExportImportLog','timelog','calculationProgress','dictionaryLog','loginServiceLog', 'calculateScenarioLog','connectionLog','dataLabelServiceLog','cross-section-service','qe-basic-executor-service','qe-plan-enumerator-impl-service','qe-basic-planenum-ssservice','ct-dimension-hierarchy-service','cbRuleLog'],additivity:true
error SNS: ['aggDataStackLog','constraintGroupLog','pageFilterLog','alertDebugLog','dacCacLog','tpFlagExportImportLog','timelog','calculationProgress','dictionaryLog','loginServiceLog', 'calculateScenarioLog','connectionLog','dataLabelServiceLog','cross-section-service','qe-basic-executor-service','qe-plan-enumerator-impl-service','qe-basic-planenum-ssservice','ct-dimension-hierarchy-service','cbRuleLog'],additivity:true
//info SNS: ['aggDataStackLog','calculateScenarioLog']
/*root {
    error 'R'
    additivity = true
}   */
```

}

Here is the test code which I ran.

```
  @TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class FooSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
}

def cleanup() {
}

void "test something"() {
    println "****************testing in real "
    assertTrue(1==1)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the test case like this

```
grails test-app unit: KpiLog
```

The important thing is that you use `unit:` instead of `-unit` and `KpiLog` instead of `KpiLogSpec`

Then do not define the variable `log`.

```
def log = new KpiLog(scenarioId: 1, kpiId: 2, deltaKpi: 5)
```

It is reserved for logging in Grails classes (controllers, services, ...). Rename the variable  from `log` to `kpiLog`

```
def kpiLog = new KpiLog(scenarioId: 1, kpiId: 2, deltaKpi: 5)
```

A simple log configuration can be

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n')
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @saw303. Now I can see that it is running the test cases however it is still failing with "  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: className for class: org.junit.runner.Description"

Comment: I extended my answer. Please review it

Comment: I modified it to kpiLog. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have your run `grails clean`? Then have you tried to isolate the problem by only using a simple console appender? Your logging config could be part of the problem.

Comment: I tried multiple combinations for logging with any success. I am still getting the same error. Can you please suggest a simple logging which will spit everything on console. I will try that also

Comment: please find the log config above

Comment: I tried above logging also. I ran grails clean after changing the logging config. Now I am not getting the error message but the problem is still there because the message I am getting is "Completed 0 spock test, 0 failed in". That was the original problem

Comment: create a new unit test by using `grails create-unit-test Foo` and implement only one simple test. Let me know what happens.

Comment: This is what I get "Tests PASSED - view reports in D:\workspace_idea_new\optapp\target\test-reports". It does not even show how many test cases completed or run

Comment: Please see the test code above. Same code runs fine if I create a new grails app.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it is working. It was because of the jar msutil in the lib folder. I got this information from one of my friends that it has some incompatibility. I changed the jar which he sent and things started working.

Thanks a lot saw303 for keeping patience with my questions.